# whats causing the migration to fail with error " there can only be on auto increment column"

Tags: php, laravel

My table posts does not have any limits, i am letting `Laravel` choose the auto increment by default. It still fails with “there can only be on auto increment column”.

### migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->id('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->id('admin_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('about')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('price')->nullable();
        $table->string('new_used')->nullable();
        $table->string('negotiable')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('expire_date')->nullabe();

      
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't use `id()` on multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple auto incremented columns. Change the foreign keys type to `unsignedInteger()` and it should work. This is usually the way i create and id column plus two foreign keys.

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
$table->unsignedInteger('admin_id')->nullable();
```

Alternatively you can create a foreign key reference also.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: thanks it worked its just confusing me with another error if you would help..........`
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `zipad`.`posts` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter 
table `posts` add constraint `posts_id_foreign` foreign key (`id`) references `users` (`id`))`

Comment: You have duplicate foreign key names, are you trying the exact code as specified in this answer? never the less, second parameter of foreign('user_id', 'foreign_key_name') you can customize the foreign key names.

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `id` method on `Blueprint` is an alias for `bigIncrements` which creates a Unsigned Big Integer Autoincrement field.

So you have 3 autoincrement fields in that migration for that table and you can only have 1.